# htaccess to remove part of a url, .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how it is possible to remove part of a url with htaccess for example I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost/item.php?pa=gd34392
```

now I need to use **htaccess** to redirect this page or anything like this to a page with this url:

```
http://localhost/gd34392
```

I have tried things like this but nothing seems to work and I do not really know my way around htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule item.php?pa=$1 /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the following rules in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /item.php?pa=$1 [L]
```

Just make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: it gives me 500 internal error when i insert it in my .htaccess file

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Have you activated `mod_rewrite` on Apache?

Comment: yes mod_rewrite is activated and still get 500 internal until i remove .htaccess file